# Listiview with Array

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist

How can I create a listview that looks for more than one information in an array?

An example, suppose I have a listview of names from an array, but I still have another array that contains data like age and profession that match each name of the first array.

How could I get more than one information from an array?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Make a custom model for your data, store whole data in a object of that class, and make ArrayList of those objects then pass to adapter for lisview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening when you load an ArrayList into an ArrayAdapter, and then an ArrayAdapter into a ListView, is the ArrayAdapter uses a layout file which contains a TextView. The ArrayAdapter takes the string in each ArrayList element, inflates (creates) a new View with a layout per ArrayList element, and then places the element string in each new layout's TextView.

If you want to customize each row's visual appearance (including what data appears) in your list on the screen, you can make your own custom Adapter by making a new class that extends BaseAdapter and you can make your own layout file that you will inflate in the BaseAdapter. Then find the elements in your layout and assign the data to the elements on a per row basis. Below is example code I wrote for you. I would highly suggest reading the Android documentation on ListViews and Adapters: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

In my activity OnCreate method (You will need to have a ListView in your layout called list_view or change the name of the ListView in my code):

```
    ArrayList<MyDataModel> myDataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        MyDataModel newModel = new MyDataModel("Person" + i, new Random().nextInt() % 100, "Some Profession" + i);
        myDataModels.add(newModel);
    }

    MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(myDataModels);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

MyDataModel.java:

```
public class MyDataModel {

    public String mName, mProfession;
    public int mAge;

    public MyDataModel(String name, int age, String profession) {
        mName = name;
        mAge = age;
        mProfession = profession;
    }
}
```

MyListAdapter.java:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<MyDataModel> mMyDataModels;

public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<MyDataModel> dataModels) {
    mMyDataModels = dataModels;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mMyDataModels.size();
}

@Override
public MyDataModel getItem(int position) {
    return mMyDataModels.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_data_model_item, parent, false);
    }
    MyDataModel model = mMyDataModels.get(position);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.person_name)).setText(model.mName);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.person_age)).setText(String.valueOf(model.mAge));
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.person_profession)).setText(model.mProfession);
    return view;
}
}
```